# Inherit from const type passed as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

The following code is not valid:

```
struct base {
};

struct inherit : const base {
};
```

You cannot inherit from a `const` type.

Does the situation change when templates are involved? In other words, is this code valid:

```
struct base {
};

template<typename T>
struct inherit : T {
    using T::T;
};

int main() {
    inherit<base const>{};
}
```

gcc is says it is fine, but clang reports

```
<source>:6:2: error: 'const base' is not a direct base of 'inherit<const base>', cannot inherit constructors

        using T::T;

        ^        ~

<source>:10:2: note: in instantiation of template class 'inherit<const base>' requested here

        inherit<base const>{};

        ^

1 error generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

To make clang happy, I need to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct inherit : T {
    using U = std::remove_const_t<T>;
    using U::U;
};
```

Which version is correct? Or are neither of them correct and I need to inherit from `std::remove_const_t<T>`?

Comment: Aren't the top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter ignored when determining its type?

Comment: Your "is this code valid" mixes two things; inherit-from-`T` and the `using` clause.  Clang seems to dislike the using clause, but not the inherit-from-`T`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Only when template argument deduction happens, which doesn't happen if like OP you explicitly specify the template arguments.

Comment: @Justin That is somewhat convincing.  A possible out I can see is if the template substitution text somehow talks about stripping modifiers from type names when `T` is used in some contexts.  Proving an exception like that is never stated is hard.

Comment: @Justin I'd disagree, because it says *name* and not type.

Comment: @Justin http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#5

Comment: @rustyx http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#3

Comment: The non-template form is ill-formed because the grammar doesn't allow cv-qualifiers at that location. The template form is well-formed and clang's diagnostic message is complete nonsense.

Comment: You don't need a template to reproduce this: `using cbase = const base;` and inherit from `cbase` is enough.

Comment: I've sent a [patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/D47419) to clang.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) we have:

According to [[temp.param]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.param#3):

> A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* (if declared with `class` or `typename`) ... in the scope of the template declaration.

So it works just like a `typedef`.

And then [[class.name]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.name#5):

> If a *typedef-name* that names a *cv-qualified* class type is used where a *class-name* is required, the *cv-qualifiers* are ignored.

Hence GCC is right, `const` should be stripped when inheriting from `T`, since a *class-name* is required [at that point](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.derived#nt:class-or-decltype), as well as in the [`using T::T;`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.qual#2.2) *inheriting constructors* declaration.

Comment: Yes; and I would add that `using T::T;` is allowed here because of both [class.name]/5 already quoted and [class.qual]/2.2, which specifies that since the identifier `T` repeats, the name is "considered to name the constructor" without any lookup for a name `T` in the class.